# How to retrieve Salesforce Page Layout Field Properties via API?

Tags: api, salesforce, page-layout

**Context:**

- The Web interface coded in .NET (Grantee Portal for nonprofits applying for grants) is pulling information from the Salesforce Page Layout.
- The Salesforce user we use to connect the Web interface with Salesforce via API has 'view all and edit all' rights

**Issue:**

As it is now, if a field is defined as Read-Only on the Page Layout in Salesforce, it is still editable on the web page (the Salesforce User we use has to have 'view all and edit all' rights)

**What we are trying to achieve:**

- IF a field is defined as Read-Only on the Salesforce Page Layout
- THEN the same field should be Read-Only on the Web interface page

**Question:**

To achieve the above, I guess that I need to fetch the field property for the Page Layout via API. Any ideas on how to do so?

Thank you!
Izumi.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need Metadata API (the set of webservices that let you add new objects, fields, picklist values or even create classes & run unit tests).

Here's the API Guide: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/index.htm

Depending on how often you modify layouts you might decide "screw it, I'll just use Eclipse IDE". In that case you'd download all page layouts (they're XML files), point your C# app to them and let the magic happen.

Slightly more advanced is to use Migration Tool (Ant / Java based application that can be scripted for periodic download of same stuff).

Super advanced would be to use this API guide to write it in C#. It's not rocket science (here's the [specification for Page Layout object](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_layouts.htm) and here's the [Java sample code for the operation that retrieves the metadata](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_retrieve.htm)... sorry, no C#). Actually you might be better off looking at this example though: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describelayout.htm

Seeing that you'll probably want to cache this info somewhere anyway (I can't imagine your user coming to your page, having to wait for the webservice callout to complete, then having his UI rendered) - pick your poison.

Or share the work within the team (1 person kicks off with files downloaded with Eclipse, other tries to figure out the C# code to retrieve them on demand).